# Why does String.format accept ints in place of %s?

Tags: java, string, string-formatting, string.format

Looking at a couple of references for Java String.format(), I see they mention it has the following format:

```
public static String format(String format, Object... args)
```

So it allows me to write the following:

```
String newStr = String.format("%s,%s,%s", 1, 2, 3);
```

But I cannot do this:

```
String newStr = String.format("%d,%d,%d", "1", "2", "3");
```

Why can i use ints in place of %s but not vice-versa? Is it doing type-conversion from int to string itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. For `%s` it calls `toString` on whatever you set in there. That works for everything in Java (may produce funny output though).

For `%d` you need to give an integral type (like `Integer`, `Long` or `BigInteger`). No automatic conversion is attempted.

You can read more about it in [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) (look at the section about Conversions).

Comment: So then is it considered bad practice to use ints where %s is defined? Or would calling toString on the value be redundant?

Comment: No, it is fine to use `%s` on everything when you want to get the `toString` output. Use `%d` for extra clarity or if you need to control formatting (such as number of digits). Calling `toString` yourself on the parameter is redundant/counterproductive/not-null-safe.